# Google structured data AggregateRating works in page but not in another

Tags: google-search, schema.org, rich-snippets

I'm trying to put Google structured data in my website but it works for one page but not another. However I have the same HTML code for Google tags and Google structured data tester gives me the same result for those URL:

[URL which Google structured data doesn't work](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool?hl=fr#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.pieces-suz.com)

[URL which Google structured data works](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool?hl=fr#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.pieces-suz.com%2Fsuzuki-moto)

You can try but searching **pieces-suz suzuki-moto** in Google search. The first link doesn't display stars and the second displays those.

Why stars are not displayed on the first link ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finaly, Google doesn't display rating for homepage.

So, it's a standard behaviour.

Source : https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/rMSG5X3TctU